# Grep for pattern exclusive of matching pattern if at start of line

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep through a file of files, with path, for arbitrary patterns (given at runtime)

The problem is that I do NOT want to match those arbitrary patterns if they're in the "library path" portion of the line. But not all lines start with the library path.

I.E. given a file:

```
/other/more.mp3
/home/more/Music/more.mp3
/home/more/Music/Music.mp3
/home/more/Music/something other.mp3
/home/more/Music/other/something.mp3
```

and a "library" path of "/home/more/Music"

The pattern "Music" should match only line 3.
The pattern "more" should match lines 1 and 2, but not 3.
The pattern "other" should match lines 1,4, and 5.

Things I've tried:

```
^\($LIBRARY\)\+.*$PATTERN
^\($LIBRARY\).*$PATTERN
```

I *could* pre-process the file to remove $LIBRARY and re-add it after, probably by finding the matching line in the original file. But that seems a bit excessive, surely there's a simpler way?

Comment: Maybe `^$LIBRARY/$PATTERN[^/]*$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That won't match the first line.

Comment: Group paths into an array based on their versions where library parts are removed and have that array stored as a value of a hash where the key is the no library part version. Then you match the pattern against the keys. This can be easily done in Ruby.

Comment: Do you have to do this with `grep`? It will be much easier in just about any programming language, since you can use an `if` statement to check whether the pathname begins with the library.

Comment: The pattern is required to be able to match both arbitrary portions of the filename, AND portions of the path not including the library. Thank you, I've added clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is more suited for this job than `grep`.

```bash
awk -v pat='more' -v lib='/home/more/Music' '{
         s = $0; sub("^" lib, "", s)} s ~ pat' file

/other/more.mp3
/home/more/Music/more.mp3

# or else
awk -v pat='other' -v lib='/home/more/Music' '{
         s = $0; sub("^" lib, "", s)} s ~ pat' file

/other/more.mp3
/home/more/Music/something other.mp3
/home/more/Music/other/something.mp3

# or else
awk -v pat='Music' -v lib='/home/more/Music' '{
        s = $0; sub("^" lib, "", s)} s ~ pat' file

/home/more/Music/Music.mp3
```

---

##### Alternative `gnu grep` solution:

```bash
lib='/home/more/Music'

# test 1
grep -ioP "^(?>$lib|).*more" file

/other/more
/home/more/Music/more

# test 2
grep -ioP "^(?>$lib|).*other" file

/other
/home/more/Music/something other
/home/more/Music/other

# test 3
grep -ioP "^(?>$lib|).*Music" file

/home/more/Music/Music
```

Note the use of [atomic group in this regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), which is required to make sure we always match `$lib` at the start when it is there.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbbdY5/2)

Comment: Both those solutions are spot on, and passed every test I threw at them. The "atomic group" is exactly the thing I was looking for, thank you. Eliminate further match attempts in the matched section of the string.

Answer (score -1):

the most basic form of `ERE` suffices -

```
___='/home/more/Music/'

for __ in Music more other; do

    echo "\n :: $__ ::\n\n$( 

        echo '/other/more.mp3
              /home/more/Music/more.mp3
              /home/more/Music/Music.mp3
              /home/more/Music/something other.mp3
              /home/more/Music/other/something.mp3' | 

        {m,g,n}awk      '$NF ~ __'  FS="^$___" __="$__"
                                                       -- or --
        {m,g,n}awk 'index($NF, __)' FS="^$___" __="$__"

    )\n"

done | gcat -b
```

——

```
 1   :: Music ::

 2  /home/more/Music/Music.mp3


 3   :: more ::

 4  /other/more.mp3
 5  /home/more/Music/more.mp3


 6   :: other ::

 7  /other/more.mp3
 8  /home/more/Music/something other.mp3
 9  /home/more/Music/other/something.mp3
```

Comment: Your testing framework is cute, but kind of horrific variable name choices there. Substituting a variable number of underscores for "$LIBRARY" and "$PATTERN" does nothing good for readability! This could have been and should have been condensed to the two lines of awk invocations, and then expanded to explain how they're being invoked and why. In particular, explain what "NF" and "FS" are, and how assigning __="$__" makes sense in context.

Comment: @JohnGilmore: i'l give u a hint `__="$__"` isn't a shell variable assigning into itself. `FS` is `"field separator"` i.e. `delimiter regex for auto splitting input rows into "fields" (columns)`, the same way tabs are used to split `.TSV`, and that within the fields/columns, by definition, none of the stuff matches the `FS` regex. `NF` is # Fields (# columns), so `$NF` is right most column……….

Comment: ………... Use the `-p-  -d- ` flags in `gawk` if you wanna see more details of  what it actually does (those 2 flags can't combinable cuz the suffix dash in each means i'm sending both to `STDOUT` - if you ran it as `gawk -d-p-` what happens instead is a file literally named `-p-` being created with its output)

Comment: @JohnGilmore : in this particular question, using `FS` and `$NF` together has same effect as that atomic-grouping / once-only-subexpression thing without needing `PCRE`

Comment: I see I wasn't clear enough. I'm not complaining that I can't understand your answer, I'm saying that your answer is neither clear, nor easily comprehensible. Therefore, please edit it in the manner described in my first comment. The comments you made should mostly have gone into that edit.

Comment: It's not really relevant what __="$__" is actually doing, because that's not the problem. The problem is you chose variable names as if competing in an "incomprehensible code" contest, not in a manner that could actually contribute to the discussion. Go change the variable names to match what the rest of this question used instead of something that looks chosen to save keystrokes and make people squint and count characters.

Comment: Your answer is a good approach, and is a valuable addition. It will be more valuable if it's easy and quick to be understood.

Comment: @JohnGilmore : `b='/home/more/Music/'; for a in Music more other; do awk '$NF ~ a'  FS="^$b" a="$a"; done` ::::::: not sure how this helps with readability - calling it `$LIB` / `$LIBRARY` is also partially misleading since the search criteria you listed doesn't constrain results to definitively contain the path prefix as defined by `$LIBRARY`. `a="$a"` means i'm assigning the value of the shell variable `"$a"`, whether it exists or not, into an `awk` internal variable with the same name.

Comment: The point is to avoid a focus on the framework, and enhance the speed of understanding. Part of that is to not change the terms. The question and the previous answer already chose names, changing them requires the person reading to re-focus. Also, adding a testing framework *to the answer* doesn't help understand the meat of the answer, but instead wastes cognitive effort on understanding the framework.

Comment: "This can be done with awk and basic ERE, like this: "awk      '$NF ~ PATTERN'  FS="^$LIBRARY" __="$PATTERN" " --- Here we use $LIBRARY as a field seperator, assiging it to the special awk variable NF. This forces awk to not consider it as part of the string when searching for $PATTERN. Since fields aren't required to be separated, this works both with and without the presence of $LIBRARY at the start of the string.

Comment: Presenting the information like that (though perhaps with an expanded/corrected explanation. I'm really not very familiar with awk, and of course with better formatting) focuses precious brainpower on understanding how your answer works, and avoids wasting it on appreciation of your clever testing framework or usage of unfamiliar variables.